# Angular2 foreach object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Array of Objects called comments, and I'm trying to select only one's that have the id of post that I need to another array of objects. And the problem is that I can't find a way to copy the object I have found. This is my function:

```
comments = [];
commentspart = [];
private loadPartComments(id){          
            this.comments.forEach(element => {
            if (element.postId == id) {
                this.commentspart = ????;
                }
            });
            return this.commentspart;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about: `this.commentspart = element;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i guess you are looking for `filter`,

```
    comments = [];
commentspart = [];
private loadPartComments(id){          
            this.commentspart = this.comments.filter(element => {
               return element.postId == id;
            });
        }
```

it will give you filtered array of comments based upon id.

Hope this helps!!